# Google Simple API Access - Authorization required, but how?

Tags: google-api

I'm trying write a standalone perl app that list all my tasks stored in Google Tasks. I'm led to believe I can use what Google call "Simple API Access" because it's just my tasks and it's read only.

So I did the following:

```
#!perl
use LWP;
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $list = "Iyrhxu8sRTVOhE4hUBr4W1kwNTI6MDow";
my $key = "<api key removed>";
my $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/lists/$list/tasks?pp=1&key=$key";
print $browser->get($url)->content;
```

In return, I get:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Unfortunately I've no idea what authorization it wants at this point. I tried replacing the last line with:

```
my $auth = "...";
print $browser->get($url, "Authorization", $auth)->content;
```

and using the Google listed Client ID, Email address and Client Secret listed in the API Console - but they all gave `Invalid Credentials`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: No, I never managed to find a solution and so gave up. Sorry.

Comment: After researching it quite a bit, it doesn't seem to be available.  I don't know why they still mention 'simple api access' in the api key section.  It does mention "depreciated" in a few places, but it's really just off.  Use oauth2 - https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem to work, they seem to have disabled it in favor of oauth2, and just haven't updated the apply-for-an-api-key page.  Use Oauth2 instead:

```
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
```

If you need an api key, you can get it here:

```
https://code.google.com/apis/console
```